# knitr: Referring to and evaluating external code chunks

Tags: r, knitr

How could I **refer to and evaluate** (in an `.Rmd` file) *specific chunks* of R code, located not in a different `.Rmd` file, but in an `R` module, containing chunks of code, tagged with `## @knitr chunk_name`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out what the problem was: I have simply forgotten to call `read_chunk()` function for the `R` module, containing those external code chunks. So far, everything appears to be working, with the *exception*, mentioned below.

One problem I'm currently experiencing (and this might be a good separate question, but I'll leave it as is for now) is that `knitr` doesn't seem to respect working directory and paths, constructed on its basis, using *relative paths*, such as `file.path(getwd(), "data/transform")`. I think this contradicts with `knitr` design, which allows **code reuse** via chunks in *external* R modules. What are approaches that people are using to solve this peculiar situation? I believe that it might be a good idea to submit as a feature request.

Comment: Relative paths are relative to the directory of the input file by default, as explained in the Note section of the documentation `?knitr::knit`.

Comment: @Yihui: Thanks, I read that. My problem is specific to the situation with having **multiple** *parent* and *child* documents in various directories. In this case, I think it would be optimal, if `knitr` would use paths relative to the one set in `root.dir`. I guess that's the reason you introduced this feature. However, it appears to be broken. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/25705821/2872891.

Comment: @Yihui: As a **workaround**, for now I resorted to reading an *environment variable* set to project's home directory. I look forward to hearing your opinion on whether there is an bug in `knitr`, related to `root.dir`, or not and what I'm missing in this case.