# Working directory issues with knitr - parent and child R Markdown documents

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I'm having working directory issues when using `knitr` with *parent* and *child* `R Markdown` documents and *external* chunks from my `R` code. I've described the situation and provided links to my code here: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/38 (the issue is closed, but relevant, so I decided to leave my comment there). Would appreciate your help on this! (A copy of this has also been posted to knitr Google Groups.)

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/38#issuecomment-54708412) your issue post? You're not going to get many takers here at SO unless you include a [self-contained reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in your question.

Comment: @Ben: Yes, that is my issue post. Since the issue was closed, I thought that I'm doing something so obviously wrong, so it's easy to see just by reading the description and looking briefly at the code. In the meantime, I will try to create a reproducible example for this issue.

Comment: @Ben: BTW, I've posted two comments to your nice answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15376462/2872891. I'm mentioning this, just in case you haven't received a notification (sometimes SO does that for comments).